# Is this a viable, monotonically increasing timeId in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

[NodeJS 10.x/11.x]

I'm looking for an always-increasing time "id" that will be unique and monotonically increasing across processes (but not necessarily across servers). I've looked at [Monotonically increasing time in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964779/monotonically-increasing-time-in-node-js) but that's for performance timing. Basically, I'm looking for a timeId that can be persisted to a database.

Note: I've tried process.hrTime(), but on my MacMini, it's not monotonically increasing. Upgrading to Node10/11 and using hrtime.bigInt() seemed to solve part of my problem.

Here's my current idea (where bigIntToBase64String() is omitted, but does what you'd expect):

```
let startHrTime = process.hrtime.bigint();
let systemStartTime = BigInt(new Date().getTime()) * BigInt(2**16) * BigInt(2**5);

class TimeId {
    getTimeId() {
        let t1 = process.hrtime.bigint() - startHrTime;
        let ticks = t1 + systemStartTime;
        return this.bigIntToBase64String(ticks);
    };
}
```

As you can see, it's a bit of a hack. I subtract the first hrtime I get, and then add that to the system start time (which I've mangled into a BigInt). Assuming perfectly synchronized clocks (ha!) this could possibly be used as a global timeId. (For my purposes, the cross-system clock skew will hopefully be solved another way).

I'm currently configuring some tests to validate my assumption, but, since I'm still quite new to JavaScript/Node.JS, I thought I'd ask... is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: With a fix to the exponents (2 ** 16 and 2 ** 5) this works when running a process over-and-over... by sending the last timeId generated from the running process to the next process and checking that the next timeId is larger, I've kinda validated the results.

Comment: Also looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49708974/can-we-use-process-hrtime-as-uuid-in-node-js, which was actually asking a similar question, but i missed it originally.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequential-guid) and [that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequential-ids) packages, might be what you need.